# how to parse json using json_populate_recordset in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a json stored as text in one of my database row. the json data is as following

```
[{"id":67272,"name":"EE_Quick_Changes_J_UTP.xlsx"},{"id":67273,"name":"16167.txt"},{"id":67274,"name":"EE_12_09_2013_Bcum_Searchall.png"}]
```

to parse this i want to use postgresql method

json_populate_recordset()

when I post a command like

```
select json_populate_recordset(null::json,'[{"id":67272,"name":"EE_Quick_Changes_J_UTP.xlsx"},{"id":67273,"name":"16167.txt"},{"id":67274,"name":"EE_12_09_2013_Bcum_Searchall.png"}]') from anoop;
```

it gives me following error
first argument of json_populate_recordset must be a row type

note : in the from clause "anoop" is the table name.

can anyone suggest me how to use the json_populate_recordset method to extract data from this json string.

I got method's reference from 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The first argument passed to pgsql function `json_populate_recordset`should be a row type. If you want to use the json array to populate the existing table `anoop` you can simply pass the table `anoop` as the row type like this:

```
insert into anoop
select * from json_populate_recordset(null::anoop, 
        '[{"id":67272,"name":"EE_Quick_Changes_J_UTP.xlsx"},
          {"id":67273,"name":"16167.txt"},
          {"id":67274,"name":"EE_12_09_2013_Bcum_Searchall.png"}]');
```

Here the `null` is the default value to insert into table columns not set in the json passed.

If you don't have an existing table, you need to [create a row type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createtype.html) to hold your json data (ie. column 
names and their types) and pass it as the first parameter, like this `anoop_type`:

```
create TYPE anoop_type AS (id int, name varchar(100));
select * from json_populate_recordset(null :: anoop_type, 
        '[...]') --same as above
```

Comment: This is the first answer I've found that unpacks null::anoop in plain English. Thanks! That said, I don't understand the value of the null, however, as most records have many data types. Aside from null, what other defaults could we provide for a record expecting strings, uuid and ints?

Answer (score 22):

no need to create a new type for that.

```
select * from json_populate_recordset(null::record,'[{"id_item":1,"id_menu":"34"},{"id_item":2,"id_menu":"35"}]')
 AS
 (
    id_item int
    , id_menu int
 )
```

Comment: If I query from Table what would be the syntax for that without using create type

Comment: ERROR: record type has not been registered

Comment: I'm always amused when a 5-yr old question has comments only a few weeks older than my first visit...

Comment: Can even be easier: select * from jsonb_to_recordset('[{"id_item":1,"id_menu":"34"},{"id_item":2,"id_menu":"35"}]')
 AS
 (
    id_item int
    , id_menu int
 )