# Populate multiple tables from a single JSON object with json_populate_recordset

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, import, common-table-expression

I've read [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25785575/how-to-parse-json-using-json-populate-recordset-in-postgres), but unlike user kenthewala, I want to get an array of JSON objects into the database.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"tablename_a":[{"a_id":1,"b_id":2,"c_id":3},
 {"a_id":2,"b_id":51,"c_id":3}],
"tablename_b":[{"b_id":2,"name":"John Doe", "z_id":123},
 {"b_id":51,"name":"Mary Ann", "z_id":412}],
"tablename_c":[{"c_id":3, "OS type":"Windows 7"}],
"tablename_z":[{"z_id":123, "Whatever":"Something"},
{"z_id":123, "Whatever":"Something else"}]
}
```

Tables with the according names already exist in the db.

In pseudo-code I imagined something like

```
for each key in JSON_FILE as tbl_name
(
  insert into tbl_name select * from json_populate_recordset
  (
    null::tbl_name, 'content of tbl_name'
  )
)
```

But I'm not sure, how to realize this.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.5 (and PHP 5.3.3 if that helps).

The table structure resembles the JSON file (as I exported the JSON originally from the db):

```
create table tablename_a (a_id integer, b_id integer, c_id integer);
create table tablename_b (b_id integer, name text, z_id integer);
```

and so on.

Comment: Actual table definition for at least one table would be nice. `CREATE TABLE ...`. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the hint! Changed my post accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 Steps:

1. Access field of JSON object wich [**`->`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE).
2. Create a derived table from the JSON array of records using [**`json_populate_recordset()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE).
3. Decompose the row-type for the `INSERT` command.

To reuse the input value for all tables, wrap it in [data-modifying CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH input AS (
   SELECT '{
      "tablename_a":[{"a_id":1,"b_id":2,"c_id":3},
       {"a_id":2,"b_id":51,"c_id":3}],
      "tablename_b":[{"b_id":2,"name":"John Doe", "z_id":123},
       {"b_id":51,"name":"Mary Ann", "z_id":412}],
      "tablename_c":[{"c_id":3, "OS type":"Windows 7"}],
      "tablename_z":[{"z_id":123, "Whatever":"Something"},
      {"z_id":123, "Whatever":"Something else"}]
      }'::json AS j
   )
,  a AS (
   INSERT INTO tablename_a
   SELECT t.*
   FROM   input i
        , json_populate_recordset(NULL::tablename_a, i.j->'tablename_a') t
   )
,  b AS (
   INSERT INTO tablename_b
   SELECT t.*
   FROM   input i
        , json_populate_recordset(NULL::tablename_b, i.j->'tablename_b') t
   )
   -- ... more ...
INSERT INTO tablename_z
SELECT t.*
FROM   input i
     , json_populate_recordset(NULL::tablename_z, i.j->'tablename_z') t
;
```

**[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/abdb6/5)**

Using implicit `JOIN LATERAL`. Related:

- [Query combinations with nested array of records in JSON datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877241/query-combinations-for-postgresql-json-datatype/26880705#26880705)

Comment: Thanks, I currently get a syntax error with this, but you lead me into the right direction!
I must admit though, I had hoped, there's a way to somehow extract the table names as some kind of variable, so you don't have to manually write every SELECT statement.

Comment: @Picl: That's possible, too, but you need dynamic SQL for that. I have posted many related answers. [Try a search.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plpgsql+dynamic-sql) I doubt the additional effort is worth the trouble if you have a given structure anyway. As for the syntax error: the added fiddle proves that my code works.

Comment: The problem came from me thinking too much ^^.
I thought you had abbreviated your code as it was just an example. Therefor I had surrounded the last insert statement with 'z AS (...);' just as the other statements before, which was obviously the wrong way.

As there are many tables and I might not always want to update all of them at once, I guess, I'll try to go the dynamic way. Thanks for your help and the provided links!