# PostgreSQL 9.3 - How to insert using json_populate_recordset but still get auto ids by sequence

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

This is a followup question to "[Populate multiple tables from a single JSON object with json_populate_recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043450/populate-multiple-tables-from-a-single-json-object-with-json-populate-recordset)".

Say my tables (table_a, table_b) have sequences for a_id and b_id,
so they look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (a_id serial, b_id integer, c_id integer);
CREATE TABLE table_b (b_id serial, name text, z_id integer);
...
CREATE TABLE table_z (z_id serial, some_text_entry text);
```

A regular insert looking like this

```
INSERT INTO table_a (b_id, c_id) values (1, 2);
INSERT INTO table_b (name, z_id) values ("whatever", 3);
...
INSERT INTO table_z (some_text_entry) values ("Some text");
```

lets PostgreSQL increment the ids for a_id (table_a), b_id(table_b), etc., so the new dataset can be created and stored.

But how could I insert data using the more complex approach following and still get automatically created ids?

```
WITH input AS (
   SELECT '{
      "tablename_a":[{"a_id":1,"b_id":2,"c_id":3},
       {"a_id":2,"b_id":51,"c_id":3}],
      "tablename_b":[{"b_id":2,"name":"John Doe", "z_id":123},
       {"b_id":51,"name":"Mary Ann", "z_id":412}],
      "tablename_z":[{"z_id":123, "some_text_entry":"Something"},
      {"z_id":123, "some_text_entry":"Something else"}]
      }'::json AS j
   )
,  a AS (
   INSERT INTO tablename_a
   SELECT t.*
   FROM   input i
        , json_populate_recordset(NULL::tablename_a, i.j->'tablename_a') t
   )
,  b AS (
   INSERT INTO table_b
   SELECT t.*
   FROM   input i
        , json_populate_recordset(NULL::tablename_b, i.j->'tablename_b') t
   )
   -- ... more ...
INSERT INTO tablename_z
SELECT t.*
FROM   input i
     , json_populate_recordset(NULL::tablename_z, i.j->'tablename_z') t
;
```

If I just set the id to null

```
"tablename_a":[{"a_id": null,"b_id":2,"c_id":3},
       {"a_id": null,"b_id":51,"c_id":3}]
```

or leave out the respective ids like this:

```
"tablename_a":[{"b_id":2,"c_id":3},
       {"b_id":51,"c_id":3}]
```

I get the error 'null value in column "a_id" violates not-null constraint'.

*In addition:*
Would be really great if there was a way to deal with this, without specifically listing all column names (except the serial-ones).

In MySQL if you take my table_a, I know you could do something like

```
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (1,2)
```

meaning that MySQL would fill the a_id field with an autoincrement id and the rest with the data given by the insert command. Is there no way to accomplish that with json, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when you want to insert into a table that has a column of type `serial` or `bigserial`, you omit that column from the list of columns. I tried to change your original syntax as little as possible to show how this works.

```
-- I made no changes to the CTE, except to cut some lines.
WITH input AS (
   SELECT '{
      "tablename_a":[{"a_id":1,"b_id":2,"c_id":3}, {"a_id":2,"b_id":51,"c_id":3}]
      }'::json AS j
)
-- Ignore a_id. It's set automatically by PostgreSQL. 
-- Think about cutting it from input.
INSERT INTO table_a (b_id, c_id)
SELECT b_id, c_id
FROM   input i
     , json_populate_recordset(NULL::table_a, i.j->'tablename_a') t
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this without specifically naming all columns (but the id-ones, off course)? As there are many tables and columns, it would be great, if there was a possibility to give postgres the json and it somehow just knows that it has to fill the serial field by itself.

Comment: *"Is there a way to do this without specifically naming all columns..."* I can't think of an easy way off the top of my head.

Comment: I was assigned to another project in the meantime, but now I'm back with this problem. I tried your solution, and it runs without error (-> 12 row(s) affected in 45ms), but it doesn't actually insert anything. As most examples with INSERT and named columns also use VALUES, I tried to insert that in front of "SELECT b_id, c_id". But that doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

Comment: I copied and executed your `CREATE TABLE table_a...` statement and the query in my answer. Ran without error, created two rows. It doesn't make sense for PostgreSQL to report 12 rows affected without inserting 12 rows. Check the tables and your query carefully. If you're using pgAdminIII, look at the "history" tab, too.

Comment: My bad, sorry. I tried the query from within my editor, which has some automatic reverse after execution (like a not committed transaction). So, yeah, it works :-)

Comment: Wonderful, It can use for multiple tables