# How do I define a record type for JSON in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Looking at postgres documentation for JSON functions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html), there is a section I don't understand about expanding a JSON object into a set of rows.

The docs give a sample use of this function: `json_populate_recordset(base anyelement, from_json json)` as `select * from json_populate_recordset(null::myrowtype, '[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]')`

But I'm not sure what that first argument `(null::myrowtype)` is -- a table definition?

The description of this function is: Expands the outermost array of objects in from_json to a set of rows whose columns match the record type defined by base (see note below).

None of the notes at the bottom seemed relevant.  I'm hoping for a better explanation with sample code to understand it all.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26742370/237955), it looks like you can use `null::mytablename` in that place, but I don't understand that syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd notice is the one of interest in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) as it explains how missing fields/values are handled

> Note: In json_populate_record, json_populate_recordset, json_to_record
>   and json_to_recordset, type coercion from the JSON is "best effort"
>   and may not result in desired values for some types. JSON keys are
>   matched to identical column names in the target row type. JSON fields
>   that do not appear in the target row type will be omitted from the
>   output, and target columns that do not match any JSON field will
>   simply be NULL.

`json_populate_recordset` maps the name of the json object to the column name in the table given as first argument.

```
create table public.test (a int, b text);

select * from json_populate_recordset(null::public.test, '[{"a":1,"b":"b2"},{"a":3,"b":"b4"}]');


 a | b
---+----
 1 | b2
 3 | b4
(2 rows)

--Wrong column name:
select * from json_populate_recordset(null::public.test, '[{"a":1,"c":"c2"},{"a":3,"c":"c4"}]');
 a | b
---+---
 1 |
 3 |
(2 rows)


--Wrong datatype:
select * from json_populate_recordset(null::public.test, '[{"a":1.1,"b":22},{"a":3.1,"b":44}]');

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1.1"
```

Alternatively, instead of using the column name/type from an existing table, you can define the columns on the fly

```
select * from json_to_recordset('[{"a":1,"b":"foo"},{"a":"2","c":"bar"}]') as x(a int, b text);
 a |  b
---+-----
 1 | foo
 2 |
(2 rows)
```

--> note that default type cast occurs ("2" is mapped to 2), missing fields are ignored (b, in second record) as well as fields not defined (c)